# Where can I put \noalign?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am writing the a command to generate a table of #1 rows and #2 columns. It produces the table but everywhere I put the `\noalign` I get a message saying it was misplaced.

The code is:

```
\renewcommand{\table}[2]{ \newcounter{loop1} \newcounter{loop2}

\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}

 %Title:

 \noalign \\

 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{#1}{X|}}  \hline

 \forloop{loop1}{1}{\value{loop1}<#1}{ hi & sa } %first box \\ \hline

 \forloop{loop2}{2}{\value{loop2}<#2}{

 \forloop{loop1}{1}{\value{loop1}<#1}{ hi & sa } \\ \hline}

 \forloop{loop1}{1}{\value{loop1}<#1}{ hi & sa } %Last box \\ \hline

 \end{tabularx} }
```

And the `\noalign` is the one below the word 'Title'. How can I place this so that my table (and preferably the word 'Title') are not indented? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\forloop` etc. in tables is tricky due to grouping etc. The `\renewcommand{\table}` is not recommended at all!

Comment: What is the precise content of your table? `hi` and `sa`???

Comment: @ChristianHupfer they will in the end just be empty cells, I just put 'hi' and 'sa' in so I could see it was working properly. Actually I think I have solved the problem. I was meant to be using \noindent rather then \noalign.

Comment: Of course `\noindent` and `\noalign` are very different things ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a `expl3` solution with `\prg_replicate:nn` which survives the end of the cell groups. Its replication feature is the right tool for producing empty cells etc, as meant for manual fill-in forms, e.g. class lists or member lists in a meeting etc.

`\prg_replicate:nn` is much easier than a bunch of `\forloop` statements.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colrowtable}{mm}{%
  \prg_replicate:nn {#1}{%
    #2%
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytable}{mmm}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{#2}{X|}}  
    \hline
    \colrowtable{#1}{#3\tabularnewline\hline}
\end{tabularx}  
}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
Table
\bigskip

\mytable{10}{4}{hi & sa & do & now}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]